# In gdb, what's the difference between 'where', 'bt', and 'i frame' commands?

Tags: gdb, where-clause, frame, info

Seems they all print out information about what's the current call frame is, and 'i frame' seems to give a bit more information. But I don't really see the necessity of 'where' command. Is there anything that 'where' command can do while 'bt' or 'i frame' cannot do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`where` and `bt` are exact synonyms and produce exact same output. From the [manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20210620190613/https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html#Backtrace):

```
The names where and info stack (abbreviated info s) are additional
aliases for backtrace.
```

`info frame` is totally different: it describes *current* frame, not the call stack.

> I don't really see the necessity of 'where' command

It's there to make life easier for people who first used another debugger (e.g. `dbx`).